# Whats wrong with my code for checking if a site is online or not?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-websettings

I had been working on a app for my college project. It that application i just want to check if a website is available(online) or not. If it is available then open it in webview and if it isn't open a pre specified website.

After some research I landed up till the following code but it does not seem to work. App always opens bing.com (i.e value of flag does not get updated after running pingHost)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView web1;
    String Address;
    int flag=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
        repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pingHost("http://www.google.com", 80, 5000);
                        if (flag==1) {
                            web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                            Address = "https://learn2lead.home.blog";
                            WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
                            webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                            webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                            web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                            web1.loadUrl(Address);
                        } else if (flag==0){
                            web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                            Address = "http://bing.com";
                            WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
                            webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                            webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                            web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                            web1.loadUrl(Address);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 10000);

    public void pingHost(final String host, final int port, final int timeout) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);
                    flag = 1;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }


        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to wait for `pingHost` to return before using the `flag` value, why does it need to be a seperate thread?

Comment: @ScaryWombat but it's scheduled to run at fixed interval

Comment: On first glance you seems to be a victim of Asynchronous Call . `pingHost` method running of separate thread .  So `flag` is always 0  inside `TimerTask` . You need wait for it to ping competed first .

Comment: Did you wait 10secs to see if it changes to the website you want? Also log the exception in `pingHost` instead of ignoring it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat App gives runtime error Network on main thread if it is not on sepreate thread

Comment: Yes it does not change after 10 seconds. and sadly i dont know how to log because I only started using android studio 2 days back

Comment: try `Log.d("tag", e)` or `e.printStacktrace()` before `flag = 0;`

Comment: @ADM how can i do so?

Comment: return the Thread and use `Thread::join`

Comment: I am really beginner in android studio programming. can anyone please do the edits in code and answer here ... sorry for the trouble but i am not able to understand many things that you are saying. @Kartik

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView web1;
String Address;
int flag = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
    repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isInternetAvailable()){
                flag = 1;
            }else{
                flag = 0;
            }
            System.out.println("pingHost flag: " + flag );
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (flag == 1) {
                        web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                        Address = "https://learn2lead.home.blog";
                        WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
                        webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                        web1.loadUrl(Address);
                    } else if (flag == 0) {
                        web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                        Address = "http://bing.com";
                        WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
                        webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                        web1.loadUrl(Address);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 10000);
}

public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
        //You can replace it with your name
        return !ipAddr.equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

---

Modified your posted question to working.

But implementing you should consider about that timer task close and think it really nessary 10sec period.

---

to check whether internet available this is much reliable and fast

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        try {
            int timeoutMs = 1500;
            Socket sock = new Socket();
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);

            sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
            sock.close();

            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) { return false; }
    }
```

check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27312494/1025070

Comment: The InetAddress class has a cache to store successful as well as unsuccessful host name resolutions.

Comment: @ScaryWombat you are right. 
Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddre and check accepted ansewer.

Comment: OMG! Worked like charm... I spent two days scraching my head and thinking about it. Thank you so much... @UdayaLakmal